# How can I show information from the database in a TextFormField in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display information that is in the database to the `TextFormField`.

How can I do it??

help would be greatly appreciated

Here I leave the code and the image too

iMAGE AND CODE::

I want to display information that is in the database to the `TextFormField`.

How can I do it??

help would be greatly appreciated

Here I leave the code and the image too

Flutter/Dart

```
   **************************
    final Correo = TextEditingController();
      final Contrasena = TextEditingController();
    
      Widget FullName(NombreUsuario){
        return new Container(
            child: new TextFormField(
              controller: Correo,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
               
                labelText: 'Nombre de usuario',
              ),
            )
        );
      }
    
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
            body: Center(
              child: new Container(
                child: new ListView(
                    children:[
                      SizedBox(height: 8,),
                       FullName(NombreUsuario.text),
                      SizedBox(height: 28,),
                      
                    ]
                ),
              ),
            )
        );
        throw UnimplementedError();
      }
    }
    
    }
    *********************************
    List productFromJson(String str) => List<EditarPerfilModel>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => EditarPerfilModel.fromJson(x)));
    class EditarPerfilModel{
    
      String UsuarioContrasenia;
      String UsuarioCorreo;
    
      EditarPerfilModel({this.UsuarioPk,this.UsuarioContrasenia,this.UsuarioApodo,this.UsuarioCorreo});
    
      factory EditarPerfilModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
        return EditarPerfilModel(
            UsuarioContrasenia: parsedJson['Usuario_Con'],      
            UsuarioCorreo: parsedJson['Usuario_Correo']
        );
      }
    }
*************************************************
class EditarPerfilServices{

  Future EditarPerfil() async{
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      'Charset':'utf-8'
    };
   
    var Url= Uri.parse("http://....");
    final response = await http.get((Url),headers: headers);
    print(response.body);
    return productFromJson(response.body);
  }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you get the `String` data from your database, you can simply do :

```
final Correo = TextEditingController();
Correo.text = stringData;
```

this will set the stringData to the `TextField` or `TextFormField` which the Correo controller assigned to.

hope this helps.

Comment: I bring the information using future builder,what would the code be like??

Comment: I don't see any future builder in your code

Comment: I'm sorry, how would I do it if I want to use it with future builder with the code that I publish